# Right of a character in C#

Tags: c#

How do I get right(string) in C#?
if user="MyDomain\jKing"
I want just jking from the above string.

```
      int index;
      string user;

    index = User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\");
    user = (index > 0 ? User.Identity.Name.Substring(0, index) : "");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string user = User.Identity.Name
user= user.Remove(0, user.IndexOf(@"\")+ 1);
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution that is still robust.

Comment: you might also want to use LastIndexOf() instead, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

```
var user = User.Identity.Name;
var index = user.IndexOf("\\");
if (index < 0 || index == user.Length - 1) 
{
    user = string.Empty;
}
else 
{
    user = user.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Comment: That works but you have to watch out for if the '\' happens to be the last character so you don't get an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: After edit: Wow, that gets ugly fast whey you have to add guard code!

Comment: @Jerod - Quite frankly I think Ed has a much better answer anyway.

Comment: @Jerod - That is hilarious, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: it's crazy how something that should be this simple can get out of control in a hurry. Hopefully the User.Identity would only return a username in 'Domain\Username' or 'Username' format. I'd hope that the '\' would be an invalid character, but if it's allowed you technically would need to check to see if the username is '\', contains '\', or ends with '\'.  Maybe just better to blowup and yell at the administrator that setup the system. :-) hehe

Answer (score 3):

```
User.Identity.Name.Split(@"\")[1]
```

Comment: Of course, this will cause an exception if there is no \ in the string

Comment: Yep, sometimes the domain does not get returned in User.Identity.Name for some reason.

Comment: `User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').ElementAtOrDefault(1)` would return null instead of blowing up.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well make it re-usable.  Here are some extension methods patterned after the XLST functions `substring-before` and `substring-after` to make it generic.

Usage: `var userNm = (User.Identity.Name.Contains(@"\") ? User.Identity.Name.SubstringAfter(@"\") : User.Identity.Name);`

```
public static class StringExt {
   public static string SubstringAfter(this string s, string searchString) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) return s;
      var idx = s.IndexOf(searchString);
      return (idx < 0 ? "" : s.Substring(idx + searchString.Length));
   }

   public static string SubstringBefore(this string s, string searchString) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) return s;
      var idx = s.IndexOf(searchString);
      return (idx < 0 ? "" : s.Substring(0, idx));
   }
}
```